# Automatically resize images with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I've written this function to automatically resize a unknown number of images nested in a specified div. In other words, the width should always be 225px, the height should be changed relative to that and the original image sizes.

Unfortunately my code doesn't seem to work and the alert always returns "null". What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
$(function resizeImg() {
var height = new Array();
var width = new Array();
var newHeight = new Array();
var count = $(".floatRight").find('img').length;
if ($("img").parent().hasClass("floatRight")) {
    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        height[i] = $("img:eq(i)").height();
        width[i] = $("img:eq(i)").width();
        newWidth = 225;
        newHeight[i] = (newWidth*height[i])/width[i];
        $("img:eq(i)").css({
                "height": newHeight[i],
                "width": newWidth
                });
        alert (height[i]);
        alert (width[i]);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You don't have to set the height.  If you only set the width and leave the height unset, the image will scale proportionally.

Comment: Lots of things wrong with this.  `$("img:eq(i)")` will not work at all.  You also have to wait until the images are loaded before querying their height and width.

Comment: numerous issues, first of which is images take time to load and until loaded they won't have dimensions unless they are specified in markup. Your `if` won't work right and you aren't likely targeting the proper images

Comment: I think the Answer: 1 is perfect for you
<style>
  .floatRight img{
    width:225px;
  }
</style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your code and place the following CSS on your page:

```
<style>
  .floatRight img{
    width:225px;
  }
</style>
```

That should do the trick...